# Is my proof for this exercise correct? (stochastic convergence)

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> **Problem.** Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be identically distributed (not necessarily independent) random variables such that $E|X_1|^k<\infty$ for some $k\geq 1$. Then $$(i) \lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot P\left(|X_1|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k} \right) =0 \quad (\epsilon>0), \\(ii)\frac{1}{n^{1/k}}\cdot \max_{1\leq j\leq n} |X_j|\to_P 0.$$

**My attempt.** I've written
$$\begin{eqnarray} n\cdot P\left(|X_1|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right) &=& E\left(n\cdot \mathbf 1\{|X_1|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\} \right)
\\&=& E\left(n\cdot \mathbf 1\{\frac{|X_1|^k}{\epsilon^k}\geq n\}\right)
\\&\leq & \frac{1}{\epsilon^{1/k}}E\left(|X_1|^k\cdot 1\{\frac{|X_1|^k}{\epsilon^k}\geq n\} \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$
Then since the $k$-th moment exists, we can use Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that the expression converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. Is this a valid proof for $(i)$?

For the second claim, we need to show that $P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Is this as simple as noting that $$\begin{eqnarray}
P\left(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_j|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right) &\leq& P\left(|X_1|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right)+...+P\left(|X_n|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right)
\\&=&n\cdot P\left(|X_1|\geq \epsilon\cdot n^{1/k}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$ and then concluding that this converges to $0$ by the first part of the exercise?

Comment: Yes. And yes. $ $

Comment: Can you please explain the inequality on the third line of your proof?